# Complex query to get the last registrations is not working properly - Column not found error

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query because I want to show in the conference management page some info in a table about the last 3 registrations in a specific conference (the name of the user that did the registration, the quantity of selected  registration types and the value of the total prices of the selected registration types):

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">User that did the registration</th>
        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
        <th scope="col">Value</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($registrations as $registration)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $registration->userName}}</td>
            <td>{{$registration->participants_count}}</td>
            <td>{{number_format($registration->totalPrice, 2)}}$</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So there is the `manage()` method that gets some data and redirect the user to the conference management page with that above data:

```
 public function manage($id) // $id is the id of the conference
   ...
   $registrations = DB::table('registrations')
   ->join('participants', 'registrations.id', '=', 'participants.registration_id')
   ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'registrations.main_participant_id')
   ->join('registration_types', 'registration_types.id', '=', 'participants.registration_type_id')
   ->select(DB::raw('count(participants.registration_id) as participants_count, sum(registration_types.price) as totalPrice, users.name as userName, 
            registrations.created_at'))
  ->where('conferences.id',$conference->id)
  ->groupBy('registrations.id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

  dd($registrations)
  ....

  return view('conferences.manage')
         ->with('conference', $conference)
         ->with('registrations', $registrations)
         ->with(...);
    }
```

But its not working properly. When the conference management page is acessed it shows:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'conferences.id' in 
'where clause' (SQL: select count(participants.registration_id) as participants_count, 
sum(registration_types.price) as totalPrice, 
users.name as userName, registrations.created_at from `registrations` 
inner join `participants` on `registrations`.`id` = `participants`.`registration_id`
inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `registrations`.`main_participant_id` 
 inner join `registration_types` on `registration_types`.`id` = `participants`.`registration_type_id` 
 where `conferences`.`id` = 1 
 group by `registrations`.`id`
  order by `created_at` desc)
```

Tables structure:

```
  Conferences: id, name, user_id, ...
  Registrations: id, conference_id, user_that_did_registration
  Registration_types: id, name, conference_id, price, ...
  Participants: id, name, surname, registration_type_id
```

Comment: You're not joining `conferences` anywhere in your query.

Comment: Thanks, but also dont works with "  ->join('conferences', $conference->id, '=', 'registrations.conference_id')".

Comment: Almost there; likely need to include `conferences.id` in your `->select(DB::raw())` statement for it to be available in your `->where()` clause.

Comment: Like this? " $registrations = DB::table('registrations') ->join('participants', 'registrations.id', '=', 'participants.registration_id')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'registrations.main_participant_id')->join('registration_types', 'registration_types.id', '=', 'participants.registration_type_id') ->join('conferences', 'conferences.id', '=', 'registrations.conference_id') ->select(DB::raw('count(participants.registration_id) as participants_count, sum(registration_types.price) as totalPrice, users.name as userName,  registrations.created_at'))

Comment: ->where('conferences.id',$conference->id)
->groupBy('registrations.id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();"?

Comment: That query looks like it should work now. You've joined `conferences` properly now, so `conferences.id` should be available in the `->where()` clause. If it's not, then you mignt need to add `, conferences.id` after `registrations.created_at` in your `->select(DB::raw())` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be including the `conferences` table in the query. As long as you don't, any reference to it (in this case, within the `WHERE` clause) will prevent the query from running and will produce that error